# How to require a widget/lib in app/controller?

Tags: widget, appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy

Is it possible to access a library file under a widget/lib folder from an appController?

I tried

```
require('./widgets/com.myWidget/lib/myLib')
```

and

```
require('widgets/com.myWidget/lib/myLib')
```

All these throw error:

```
[ERROR] :  Script Error Couldn't find module: ./widgets/com.myWidget/lib/myLib for architecture: i386
```

How do I require `com.myWidget/lib/myLib.js` in `controllers/myCtrlr.js`?

Or should all lib code live only under `app/lib`?

```
app
|--assets
|--controllers
    |--myCtrlr.js
|--lib
|--models
|--styles
|--views
|--widgets
   |--com.myWidget
       |--assets
       |--controllers
       |--lib
           |--myLib.js
       |--models
       |--styles
       |--views
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access directly widget lib from your app. When you create an instance of your widget with `Widget.createWidget(widget_name, [controller_name], [params])` it load the widget.js controller.

I think the best way to access your lib is to add it in `app/lib` Because from your widget you can access your lib with `require(mylib)`

If you really want access your lib from your widget, you can create a function to export it like this :

In widget.js :

```
$.loadLib = function(){
 return require(WPATH(myLib));
};
```

In index.js :

```
var w = Widget.createWidget('com.myWidget');
var myLib = w.loadLib(); //contains myLib located in com.myWidget/lib/
```